# Beautify JSON when stringify

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

When I'm saving JSON with stringify and `fs` package it looks like this:

```
{"\"name:\"":"\"Alice\"","\"age\"": 18}
```

I don't understand why. Is there any way to prettify it like this?

```
{"name:":"Alice","age": 18}
```

Comment: It looks like that because you have strange values containing doublequotes in your object.... or it's just how the console shows it

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: That's not prettifying. Your strings are just unnecessarily wrapped in double quotes.

Comment: Please share code !

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you're running your values through a json parser twice. The reason being all your items have been first surrounded in " and then escaped again. Due to the way json works, it escapes all double quote characters with backslashes.

I would look to wherever you're generating the json string and making sure you're only parsing it once.